# jQuery UI datepicker maxDate use variable

Tags: variables, jquery-ui-datepicker, maxdate

```
    var dayspace=14;
    $('.timelastd').datepicker(
    {setDate : new Date(),
     dafaultDate: new Date(),
     dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
     minDate: new Date(), 
     maxDate: dayspace,
     appendText: "click here",
     changeYear: false,

     }).keypress(function(e) {return false;});
```

I don't know how to put the variable to the maxDate?
Why can't this work?

if I change to this ~still not work~

```
    var dayspace=14;
    $('.timelastd').datepicker(
    {setDate : new Date(),
     dafaultDate: new Date(),
     dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
     minDate: new Date(), 
     appendText: "click here",
     changeYear: false,

     }).keypress(function(e) {return false;}); 
    $('.timelastd').datepicker("option", "maxDate", dayspace);
```

Comment: its working fine.Here you set `maxDate` type `number`.So its showing number of days from today.

Comment: thanks Number is the question~ fix it~good!